# 4-column grid with an unordered list and some margin

Tags: css

For the past two hours I've been fiddling with gridding an unordered list in 4 columns inside of a div. I want to create a 4-column grid with this unordered list but also give each list item a margin right. That's where I am getting destroyed. Giving the margin, the list items collapse and break to a new line.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ea1v67km/

Here's the basic markup (I removed the content of the list items for readability)

```
<div class="products">
    <ul class="products-list">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Corresponding CSS (converted from less)

```
.products {

    margin-top: 20px;

}

.products .products-list {

    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;

}

.products .products-list li {

        float: left;

        width: 25%;               /** 25% width to divide it evenly into 4-columns **/
        height: 300px;            /** For visibility **/

        margin-right: 5px;        /** Gives spacing between items **/
        margin-bottom: 10px;

        background: #000;         /** For visibility **/

}

.products .products-list li:nth-child(n + 4) {

    padding-right: 0;

}
```

I actually have fixed it by hard-coding the width using pixels however I would like to have it responsive to different widths instead of fixed. Basically the hardest part I face is making it **responsive and dynamic**.

What I'm using:

- Bootstrap
- Less

Comment: Can there be more than 4 items, so more than 1 row?

Comment: It's four items per row, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 methods I know.

1 Using `calc()` and hoping the browser is good at it

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/ea1v67km/1/

```
.products .products-list li {
    width: calc(25% - 5px);
    margin-right: calc(20px / 3);
}
```

(don't forget to clearfix the container!)

2 Flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/ea1v67km/2/

```
.products .products-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.products .products-list li {
    width: 24%; /* You could use calc(25% - 5px) here too, if you always want a 5px gap */
}
```

There are literally hundreds of 'tutorials' about this, so shouldn't be hard to find a great solution on the line.

Comment: I knew about using the calc function however should I also provide a fallback of a fixed width?

Comment: [Calc works pretty much everywhere.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) If you're still supporting IE 8, you have to provide a fixed width that fits (like `24%`), but you'll also won't have `nth-child` support.